# AppleScript to move iCal events from one calendar to another

Tags: calendar, applescript, icalendar

Trying to script the moving of events containing a keyword from one calendar to another but hitting a wall. Any pointers? I'm currently doing something like this:

```
tell application "Calendar"
move ((events of calendar "Cal1") whose summary contains "Test") to calendar "Cal2" 
end tell
```

However, this is iCal is returning this error:

"There was an error saving calendar data.
Calendar encountered a critical error while saving to the database, and recent changes may be lost. More information may be available in the console."

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks :)
J

Comment: "What am I doing wrong?" Nothing, your code is solid - it is Apple's that is not. [https://bugreport.apple.com/](https://bugreport.apple.com/)

Answer (score 0):

This is a difficult task for AppleScript in the current version of Calendar.  It can be done by repeating through the list of target Events, making new Events based on the properties of the target Events, and then deleting the original Events.  Or you can just get my app from the [App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/filtercal/id550649401?mt=12).

Comment: Thanks Craig. Your app seems like it might be useful - I'm not quite clear from reading it's description, can I select events with a keyword search? And does it allow moving as well as copying?

Comment: It does not have a keyword search yet, but you can list Events in alphabetical and reverse alphabetical order based on Event Name and/or Event Location.  You can either Copy or Move Events between calendars.

Comment: @CraigSmith The link to App Store seems to be dead. Do you have an update? I'm not in the US if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

You can't move events with **Calendar move command**, because some properties of most events is **not initialized**. Workaround is: you should use repeat loop by events, check if the property is initaialized and do not try copy the property which is not initialized.

I use following script for this task. As is, the script **duplicates** the events (by summary condition) from one calendar to other. Uncomment 3 code lines at bottom of the script if you want **move** effect instead:

```
tell application "Calendar"
    
    set sourceCalendar to calendar id "D7D5E698-7539-4C69-8BDF-F9678CC2D0C1"
    set destinationCalendar to calendar id "FC8DDBD3-0CD9-4912-9E1E-2EF21244B023"
    set sourceDescriptions to {} -- not moved yet
    
    repeat with anEvent in (get events of sourceCalendar)
        
        set itsDescription to description of anEvent
        set eventId to uid of anEvent
        
        if itsDescription is ("Outlook ID: " & eventId) then
            set destinationDescriptions to description of events of destinationCalendar
            if (itsDescription is not in sourceDescriptions) and (itsDescription is not in destinationDescriptions) then
                set end of sourceDescriptions to itsDescription -- register the moved event
                
                tell anEvent
                    set |allday event| to allday event
                    set |start date| to start date
                    set |end date| to end date
                    set |url| to url
                    set |location| to location
                    set |recurrence| to recurrence
                    set |description| to description
                    set |excluded dates| to excluded dates
                    set |stamp date| to stamp date
                    set |summary| to summary
                end tell
                
                tell destinationCalendar
                    set newEvent to (make new event at end of events with properties {allday event:|allday event|, start date:|start date|, end date:|end date|})
                    tell newEvent
                        if not (|url| is missing value) then set url to |url|
                        if not (|location| is missing value) then set location to |location|
                        if not (|recurrence| is missing value) then set recurrence to |recurrence|
                        if not (|description| is missing value) then set description to |description|
                        if not (|summary| is missing value) then set summary to |summary|
                        if not (|excluded dates| is missing value) then set excluded dates to |excluded dates|
                        if not (|stamp date| is missing value) then set stamp date to |stamp date|
                    end tell
                end tell
                
                -- try
                -- delete (contents of anEvent)
                -- end try
            end if
        end if
        
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: I'm planning to run this script daily. How can I make it avoid creating duplicate events? The ChatGPT code I shared in my comment attempted to avoid duplicates by copying the event ID to the summary and making sure that an event with that summary didn't already exist in the destination calendar.

Also I have multiple calendars with the same name - is there a way to do it with the calendar UID?

Comment: I have updated the answer. To simplify the process and avoid worsening the speed of the script, it is assumed that your description is set in the strict form description = "Outlook ID: " & eventID (**not contains** but it **is equal**). Otherwise, 1 more repeat loop would have to be applied.

Comment: Thanks I'll try this out. The description will contain other text but I think I can figure that out.